Vim does not work properly
I just installed vim on my ubuntu. When I open a text file in terminal with Vim by vim  <fileName>.txt, the data inside text file shows up. Here is the problem.
When I try to move the cursor with hjkl, instead of moving it, the hjkl replace my text. Only after I do something else like click the mouse, press Esc or Enter, hjkl work. I tried :set showmode and nothing seems to appear on the screen.
Also I cannot press PrtScrn to capture the screen as it will process the 'h' I pressed.


I don't think this fully explains this behavior, but part of the problem could be that vim is starting in insert mode; I'd check for aliases in ~/.bashrc (assuming Bash, something like alias vim="vim -c startmode") or for stuff in ~/.vimrc first, then maybe move up the chain of the shell initialization files and check that as well

for context vim has two modes command or edit ... command allows you to navigate about whereas edit mode ignores command mode signals from keyboard,etc and makes edits ... when in edit mode hit ESC key to toggle back to command mode ... from command mode there are many ways to enter edit mode ... Welcome to Ubuntu
